# Is it safe to run esp8266 on 3.76V for long run?

Tags: esp8266

I have made a Circuit for home automation and have discovered that my esp8266 is operating on 3.7--3.8V . I want to ask is it safe to use it at this voltage or I have to step it down to 3.3v for a long run. Note- I am not using a 3.7v battery . It's just a simple circuit that is providing 3.7V.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [ESP8266EX datasheet](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/0a-esp8266ex_datasheet_en.pdf) (Table 5-1 on page 18) says that the maximum supply voltage is 3.6 V. Fix your power supply.

Comment: Thanks for the answer